# Calling methods from another class and retrieving their results (Java)

Tags: java, user-interface, recursion, iteration

I have 2 classes (IterativeVsRecursive and Sequence) and the Sequence class performs mathematical actions and returns the values to IterativeVsRecursive, or at least that is the intent.

I believe I am missing something easy, but am stumped on how to make this work.

IterativeVsRecursive Class:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.sound.midi.Sequence;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class IterativeVsRecursiveGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JLabel radioButton1Label = new JLabel();
    private JLabel radioButton2Label = new JLabel();
    private JLabel inputLabel = new JLabel();
    private JLabel resultLabel = new JLabel();
    private JLabel efficiencyLabel = new JLabel();
    private JLabel computeButtonLabel = new JLabel();
    private ButtonGroup radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    private JRadioButton radioButtonIterative = new JRadioButton("Iterative");
    private JRadioButton radioButtonRecursive = new JRadioButton("Recursive");
    private JTextField inputField = new JTextField();
    private JTextField resultField = new JTextField();
    private JTextField efficiencyField = new JTextField();
    private JButton computeButton = new JButton();
    private int efficiencyCounter;

    public IterativeVsRecursiveGUI()

    {
        super("Project 3");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 2));
        radioButtonGroup.add(radioButtonIterative);
        radioButtonIterative.setSelected(true);
        // radioButtonIterative.setText("Iterative");
        getContentPane().add(radioButtonIterative);
        radioButtonGroup.add(radioButtonRecursive);
        // radioButtonRecursive.setText("Recursive");
        getContentPane().add(radioButtonRecursive);
        inputLabel.setText("Enter number: ");
        getContentPane().add(inputLabel);
        getContentPane().add(inputField);
        computeButton.setText("Compute");
        computeButton.addActionListener(this);
        getContentPane().add(computeButton);
        resultLabel.setText("Result: ");
        getContentPane().add(resultLabel);
        getContentPane().add(resultLabel);
        resultField.setEditable(false);
        efficiencyLabel.setText("Efficiency: ");
        getContentPane().add(efficiencyLabel);
        getContentPane().add(efficiencyField);
        efficiencyField.setEditable(false);
        pack();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent button) {
        int result;
        efficiencyCounter = 0;
        if (radioButtonIterative.isSelected()) {
            result = Sequence.computeIterative(Integer.parseInt(inputField.getText()));
        } else {
            result = Sequence.computeRecursive(Integer.parseInt(inputField.getText()));
        }
        resultField.setText(Integer.toString(result));
        efficiencyField.setText(Integer.toString(efficiencyCounter));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IterativeVsRecursiveGUI IterativeVsRecursiveGUI = new IterativeVsRecursiveGUI();
        IterativeVsRecursiveGUI.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Sequence class:

```
public class Sequence {
    private int efficiencyCounter = 0;

    public int computeIterative(int input) {
        int answer = 0;
        if (input == 0) {
            efficiencyCounter++;
            answer = 0;
        } else if (input == 1) {
            efficiencyCounter++;
            answer = 1;
        } else {
            efficiencyCounter++;
            int firstTerm = 0;
            int secondTerm = 1;
            for (int i = 2; i <= input; i++) {
                answer = (3 * secondTerm) - (2 * firstTerm);
                firstTerm = secondTerm;
                secondTerm = answer;
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }

    public int computeRecursive(int input) {
        int answer = 0;
        efficiencyCounter++;
        if (input == 0) {
            answer = 0;
        } else if (input == 1) {
            answer = 1;
        } else {
            answer = (3 * computeRecursive(input - 1)) - (2 * computeRecursive(input - 2));
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
```

The intent is to have a GUI that displays the results of the Sequence class.

Comment: I should have been clear in that it is not allowing me to call the non-static methods in Sequence, but if I make them static, by adding "void", then the computeRecursive method throws an errror saying that 'void' type not allowed here.

Comment: You need to make it static if you are going to call it by the `Class` name. `public static int computeIterative(int input)`. and `public static int computeRecursive (int input)`

Comment: @3kings, that answers that issue, but now my counter won't increment when the methods are invoked.  how can I then increment efficiencyCounter?

Comment: you would also have to change that to static. `private static int efficiencyCounter`

Answer (score 1):

> I should have been clear in that it is not allowing me to call the non-static methods in Sequence, but if I make them static, by adding "void", then the computeRecursive method throws an errror saying that 'void' type not allowed here

Or, since the method is already an instance method, create an instance of `Sequence`

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent button) {
    int result;
    efficiencyCounter = 0;

    Sequence sequence = new Sequence();
    if (radioButtonIterative.isSelected()) {
        result = sequence.computeIterative(Integer.parseInt(inputField.getText()));
    } else {
        result = sequence.computeRecursive(Integer.parseInt(inputField.getText()));
    }
    resultField.setText(Integer.toString(result));
    efficiencyField.setText(Integer.toString(efficiencyCounter));
}
```